# IllegalAddException: No such namespace prefix when adding node with SAX

Tags: java, xml-parsing, sax

I would like to create a node with a namespace prefix that is not declared but SAX refuses to add it.

The offending row it:

```
contentItem = content.addElement( "d:" + columnNames[i][0] );
```

I tried to tell SAX that it should not mind:

```
  SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
  reader.setFeature( "http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false );
  reader.setFeature( "http://xml.org/sax/features/namespace-prefixes", false );
  reader.setFeature( "http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false );
```

But this does not help.

I also tried to declare an XMLReader set the feature on that and then assign the XMLReader to the SAXReader. But to no avail. This is the code, just in case:

```
  SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
  XMLReader xmlReader = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
  xmlReader.setFeature( "http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false );
  xmlReader.setFeature( "http://xml.org/sax/features/namespace-prefixes", false );
  xmlReader.setFeature( "http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false );
  reader.setXMLReader( xmlReader );
```

All I want is that SAX stop checking the validity of my XML.

Your help is highly appreciated